# how can I customize EDIT tab inside publisher portal?

Tags: wso2, registry, wso2-governance-registry

I wanted to customize EDIT tab of publisher portal of wso2 registry. Currently we have below items:

Overview
Categorization
Contacts
Interface
Security
Doc links
Tags
Taxonomy

I want to add one more item under Categorization such as below:
"Classification" with drop down menu - vital, critical, discretionary

Please let me what to look for and where to look for in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is edit the relevant RXT and add a `field` element under the table *categorization* as follows

```
<field type="options" categorization="true">
  <name label="Classification">Classification</name>
  <values>
    <value>Vital</value>
    <value>Critical</value>
    <value>Discretionary</value>
  </values>
</field>
```

Please find the relevant documentation [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance530/Refining+the+Search+Results) to configure categorization options.

Comment: Thanks @mds for your help.